# Elastic stack mapper parsing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have problem with dynamic mapping. I have field `message` that is `json` and `elasticsearch` using `json` filter plugin determines the fields of that field to be various. What can i do about it? I want to parse it and add fields - i do not care about the types of these fields.

I've get following error in `logstash`:

> [2019-02-13T13:12:20,087][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>   Could not index event to Elasticsearch. 
>       {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-2019.02.13", :_type=>"doc", :routing=>nil},
>        #], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-2019.02.13",
>        "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"uhzF5mgBmZ_b74M8qLSn", "status"=>400, 
>        "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [TestJson.payload] tried to parse field [payload] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}}

My grok file looks like that:

```
if [source] =~ ".*request_response\.json$" {

    json{
        source => "message"
        target => "TestJson"
    }

if [payload] =~ /{+/ { // check if it is an object
    mutate {
        add_field => { "type" => "%{[TestJson][type]}" }
        add_field => { "payload" => "%{[TestJson][payload]}" }
    }
} # end if payload is an object

    mutate {
        convert => {
           "type" => "string"
           "payload" => "string"
        } # end convert
    } # end mutate

 } # end if source is json

} # end filter


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9201"
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  } # end elasticsearch
```

There is json named `message`  that inside has empty `payload` or `payload` with for example `date` or more complex `object` inside.

I think that this errors occurs where the object is not enough complex in the `message` json.

I am writing this grok cause i want to make fields from nested json object.
How can i fix this error?

**EDIT:**

i added `stdout` to `logstash config` near `elasticsearch` and with command

```
 journalctl -u logstash.service --since "10 minutes ago" | grep -C 30 'Could not index event'
```

i get these logs right next to error:

```
Feb 13 15:29:02 f logstash[19144]: [2019-02-13T15:29:02,328][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-2019.02.13", :_type=>"doc", :routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x4fe8d3ae>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-2019.02.13", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"Px1C52gBmZ_b74M80KX2", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [TestJson.payload] tried to parse field [payload] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}}
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "host" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "id" => "b",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "name" => "f",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "containerized" => true,
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "architecture" => "x86_64",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "os" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "family" => "redhat",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "platform" => "centos",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "version" => "7 (Core)",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "codename" => "Core"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: }
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: },
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "pid" => "27854",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "beat" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "hostname" => "f",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "name" => "f",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "version" => "6.5.3"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: },
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "message" => "{\"type\":\"Response\",\"payload\":\"2019-02-13T15:29:00.276\"}",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "severity" => "DEBUG",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "parent" => "6fce34dc18cb0e31",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "event" => "",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "span" => "44c9f754c7ca5b58",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "@timestamp" => 2019-02-13T14:29:01.669Z,
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "input" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "type" => "log"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: },
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "thread" => "http-nio-9080-exec-54",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "service" => "bi",
--
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "@timestamp" => 2019-02-13T14:29:01.669Z,
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "service" => "bi",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "prospector" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "type" => "log"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: },
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "thread" => "http-nio-9080-exec-54",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "offset" => 3006421,
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "@version" => "1",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "input" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "type" => "log"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: },
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "tags" => [
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: ],
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "TestJson" => {
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "payload" => "",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "url" => "/bi/getTime",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "type" => "Request",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "sessionId" => 476,
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "username" => "k",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "lang" => "pl",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "contentType" => "null",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "ipAddress" => "127.0.0.1",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "method" => "POST",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "queryString" => "null"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: },
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "trace" => "6fce34dc18cb0e31",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "date" => "2019-02-13 15:29:00,277",
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: "source" => "/opt/tomcat-bo/logs/bi_request_response.json"
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: }
Feb 13 15:29:05 f logstash[19144]: [2019-02-13T15:29:05,326][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-2019.02.13", :_type=>"doc", :routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x1812fa5e>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-2019.02.13", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"Uh1C52gBmZ_b74M83KWr", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [TestJson.payload] tried to parse field [payload] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}}
```

Comment: By "grok" I assume you mean Logstash configuration file?
Have you tried adding ```stdout``` to the output section to see how the messages look after applying the filters?

Comment: yes - `logstash configuration` i am not sure how to add this `stdout` in config?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-stdout.html  


Simply add ``` stdout {} ``` above the ```elasticsearch {``` line in the output section.

Comment: Ok - i managed to see it with `journalctl -u logstash.service --since "10 minutes ago" | grep -C 30 'Could not index event'`
command.  See the udpated question.